# Multiplying value of one cell with a percentage stored in another cell based on conditional

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, calculation

Hi all seeking some help on the below problem,

I am creating a sheet in which I am creating some weighted forecasting.

I store the company name and inputs in one sheet, along with the relevant forecast (upper and lower) - see below.

[Input Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGQVA.png)

In the weighted forecast I would like it to use confidence to trigger a multiplication of the lower forecast, with the percentages stores in the control sheet (see below.)

[Control Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF6GL.png)

I want the weighted forecast to basically say - IF COMPANY A = HIGH THEN * APRIL LOWER OF COMPANY A BY 65% (STORED IN CONTROL SHEET) 
OR
IF COMPANY A = MEDIUM THEN * APRIL LOWER OF COMPANY A BY 50% (STORED IN CONTROL SHEET). 
OR
IF COMPANY A = LOW THEN * APRIL LOWER OF COMPANY A BY 30% (STORED IN CONTROL SHEET).

And so on.

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the “formula” point of view, the `OR` you use is more like an `ELSE`

Here is how to build so-called nested IFs:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-nested-formulas-and-avoiding-pitfalls-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8

edit: it is also possible to do it without IF by directly multiply the condition with the related calculation and sum up

(COMPANY A = “HIGH”) * APRIL LOWER OF COMPANY A BY 65% (STORED IN CONTROL SHEET)
+
(COMPANY A = “MEDIUM”) * APRIL LOWER OF COMPANY A BY 50% (STORED IN CONTROL SHEET).
+
(COMPANY A = “LOW”) * APRIL LOWER OF COMPANY A BY 30% (STORED IN CONTROL SHEET)